# Unable to move_uploaded_file when adding user avatars

Tags: php, html, forms, file

Back again with another newbie question. I've been working on a document that will allow users to upload their own avatars to a blog that I'm creating to learn some PHP. I've been working on this document for two days now and I've spent over six hours of searching and trying different things to fix it but I just can't get it to get past this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['name'], $target)){ 

    //good message
    echo "Your avatar was successfully uploaded."; 
    }else{
    //bad message
    echo "Your avatar couldnt be uploaded, please contact an admin."; 
    }
```

It does send the "bad message" finally after about an hour of trying different solutions but I'm not quite sure why it is giving me the "bad message", to me everything looks okay.

FULL CODE:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){


if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_FILES['avatar'])) {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if (!$con){
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

    mysql_select_db('webserver', $con);

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);                   
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $id = $row['id'];

    //Directory to save stuff
    $target = "images/useravatars"; 
    $target = $target . basename($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);

    //Save the avatar
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['name'], $target)){ 

    //good message
    echo "Your avatar was successfully uploaded."; 
    }else{
    //bad message
    echo "Your avatar couldnt be uploaded, please contact an admin."; 
    }
}else{
echo "38";
}
}
?>
```

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action='uploadavatar.php' method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Upload an avatar:
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td>
            <input type='file' name='avatar'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input enctype='multipart/form-data' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
    </p>
</form>
```

By the way I'm sorry there is probably a bunch of useless code in there, I have spent a bunch of time just getting it far enough to give me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that, you're using `move_uploaded_file()` in wrong way.
The first parameter requires a filename with its extension, without base path, like
`mypic.jpg`. The second requires a destination where that file should be uploaded.

As for your code,

Replace this,

```
//Directory to save stuff
$target = "images/useravatars"; 
$target = $target . basename($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);

//Save the avatar
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['temp'], $target)){
```

with

```
// I'd assume that dirname(__FILE__) refers to your root

//Directory to save stuff
$destination = sprintf('%s/images/useravatars/%s', dirname(__FILE__), $_FILES['avatar']['name']); 

//Save the avatar
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $destination)) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Had no idea I had to add that I just thought it was a automatic, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The location where the uploaded file is stored on disk is `$_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']`. You want to move *that*, not `$_FILES['avatar']['name']`.

Comment: Wow, *facepalm*. But after doing that fix it gives me the "good message" but still hasn't uploaded the file, suggestions?

Comment: You perhaps want to save the file with it's original name, so use `$_FILES['avatar']['name']` in the `$target`. That's not the problem, I guess.

Comment: @CT What *is* happening? Do you have error reporting on? What messages are you seeing? What are you expecting?

Comment: Using ['name'] returns "Your avatar couldnt be uploaded, please contact an admin." Using ['tmp_name'] now saves a .tmp file. I do have error reporting on but I'm not getting any parse errors. I am expecting the image I choose to upload to appear in the $target location (which is saving a .tmp file now, I'm not sure if this is what it is *supposed* to do.) Can I use the .tmp file as an image?

Comment: @CT You are using the tmp_name as target to save to...!!

Comment: $target = $target . basename($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
    
  //Save the avatar
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $target)){


That is my new code and it saves a .tmp file. What is the proper way to save images? Everything I have looked up so far seems to be saving them in this way.